# cellForRowAtIndexPath returns null when there's text in the custom UITableViewCell's UITextField

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I've been really really baffled by this for hours now, so I figured it's time to seek help!

I am trying to access the text value in a `UITextField` that is embedded in a `UITableViewCell` subclass (`QuestionCell`).

The problem is whenever I try to access the cell with the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, it will return (NULL).

```
QuestionCell *qc = (QuestionCell*)[questionsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
NSLog(@"qc %@",qc); // Gives "qc (NULL)" if there's text in the custom cell
```

This only happens if there's text entered in the `UITextField` in the custom cell. If there's no text, the cell will be returned as expected.

I am using XCode4.2 with storyboard, with a custom style and class for the `UITableViewCell`

Here's my QuestionCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuestionCell : UITableViewCell


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *correctionLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *correctionMark;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pronounLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *answerInput;

@end
```

And the cells are created with the usual delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        QuestionCell *cell = nil;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QuestionCell"];

        NSString *pronoun = nil;

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                pronoun = @"je";
                break;
            case 1:
                pronoun = @"tu";
                break;
            case 2:
                pronoun = @"il";
                break;
            case 3:
                pronoun = @"nous";
                break;
            case 4:
                pronoun = @"vous";
                break;
            case 5:
                pronoun = @"ils";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        cell.pronounLabel.text = pronoun;

        return cell;
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        ActionCell *cell = nil;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ActionCell"];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob,Thank you so much for getting back to me. My problem was that when the keyboard came up, my cell was off the top of the screen, hence I thought the problem was that I had inputted text into the cell. Thank you so much for your help, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the above code. I created a test project, inserted this `QuestionCell` (complete with `UITextField` and `UILabel` objects) and your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and everything is fine.

The `UITableView` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only returns `nil` if the cell has scrolled off the screen (and that's expected behavior). But with these six cells present, I iterated through the table's `cellForRowAtIndexPath and everything was fine, regardless if I've entered text or not.

Judging from your subsequent comments, it appears that your cell has scrolled off the screen. Yep, that will definitely cause `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to return `nil`!

Comment: Looking at the documentation for cellForRowAtIndexPath: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView nothing is mentioned about returning nil if a cell is off screen. I am having the same issue...

Comment: @Sabobin In the ["Return Value"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW16) section it says "An object representing a cell of the table or `nil` if the cell is not visible or `indexPath` is out of range."

Comment: So it does! Sorry about that, being blind. :)